# Java - How to ping local IPs to find device with web app?

Tags: java, android

I have a local device (on my wifi network) that can be accessed using a web browser. However, it regularly changes its IP (it is not fixed, and, unfortunately, can't be).

How could I write a java code, for a small android app using a webview, that could scan my network and find the device's IP, quickly and easily ? Connecting to my router everytime this happens is a real pain...

I'm trying to find the X in the following URL : 192.168.1.**X**:4600/wui

At least, I think the port (4600) and /wui part should help narrowing the search.

Any ideas ? I am completely lost there, this is way above what I can do with android studio.

Thanks ! :-)

Comment: Why webview ? Ok, with webview, if you like, you can scan the local network with Javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031625/can-i-scan-my-local-network-for-specific-open-ports-quickly . If not you can scan for a HTTP response with any http client for Android OkHttp, Retrofit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no details on your question regarding on which environment you want to do that. I can tell you there is mdns in Android or apple bonjour for ios/macos.
I am sure there something similar in linux or windows.

https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/

https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd

In android at least it is super easy to implement a network discovery service.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... for a start, what you are describing is not an (ICMP) ping.  Which is a good thing because ICMP ping wouldn't help here.

What you are actually suggesting (I think) is probing for a web server running on 192.168.1.X port 4600.  To do that you simply need to attempt to do an HTTP GET or HEAD request to (I guess) `http://192.168.1.X:4600/wui` for each `X` in 0 through 255 ... or
whatever range you are scanning.

The most likely responses will be as follows:

- An HTTP response with a 2xx status code probably means you have found it.
- An HTTP response with a 4xx or 5xx status code probably means you have found some other random web server on port 4600.  It might also indicate that your device is not working.
- A Connection Refused exception means that the IP is in use, but nothing is listing on that port.
- A Connection Timeout exception means that either the IP is not in use or a firewall is blocking that port.

That should be sufficient to find your device ... if it is connected and working properly.

There are a number of Android libraries for making HTTP requests.  I'll leave it to you to research that.  You may want to probe the IPs in parallel (e.g. using multiple threads), and/or use a short connection timeout.